# converting calendars

Tags: c#, winforms

I use these codes to convert Gregorian calendar to Julian calendar and there's no problem.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        JulianCalendar juli = new JulianCalendar();
        DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
        int day = juli.GetDayOfMonth(dt);
        int month = juli.GetMonth(dt);
        int year = juli.GetYear(dt);
        string s = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", month, day, year);
        textBox2.Text = s;
    }
```

It gives me the Julian date time but when i want to convert it again to Gregorian calendar with exactly that date time it won't work. i use these following codes for converting Julian calendar to Gregorian calendar. what's the problem?

```
 private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string juli = textBox3.Text;
        string[] parts = juli.Split('/', '-');
        JulianCalendar jul = new JulianCalendar();
        DateTime dta = jul.ToDateTime(Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]), Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        string sta = dta.ToShortDateString();
        textBox4.Text = sta;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is in the order of the paremeters. It should be (in button2_Click event)

```
DateTime dta = juli2.ToDateTime(Convert.ToInt32(parts[2]), Convert.ToInt32(parts[0]), Convert.ToInt32(parts[1]), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

because the signature of ToDateTime method is the following:

```
public virtual System.DateTime ToDateTime(int year, int month, int day, int hour, int minute, int second, int millisecond)
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked. should i do this for other calendars or just for Julian calendar?

Comment: @aliboy38 just check the signatures of methods and put year, month and day in the right places

Comment: is 2 for month and 0 for day and 1 for year?

Comment: @aliboy38 look... in you second function you parse the following string - string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", month, day, year); so 0 - month, 1 - day, 2 - year.