# Convert between calendars

Tags: c#, date, gregorian-calendar, umalquracalendar

How to convert between calendars? Here is what I have:

```
UmAlQuraCalendar hijri = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();

DateTime hijriDate = new DateTime(1434, 11, 23, hijri);
DateTime gregorianDate = ...; //
```

I need a `gregorianDate` that corresponds to the `hijriDate`.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893047/converting-calendars

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the Date saved in `DateTime` is always in the current calendar. So if the current calendar is Gregorian `hijriDate` is already in Gregorian.

```
var hijriDate = new DateTime(1434, 11, 23, hijri);
//Console writeline will show 2013-09-29 00:00:00
```

If your current calendar is `UmAlQuraCalendar` you should be able to extract a Gregorian date using:

```
var hijri = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
var cal = new GregorianCalendar();

var hijriDate = new DateTime(1434, 11, 23, hijri);
var y = cal.GetYear(hijriDate), 
var m = cal.GetMonth(hijriDate), 
var d = cal.GetDayOfMonth(hijriDate)
```

Comment: Actually, `DateTime` is always Gregorian internally, so this is slightly redundant.

Comment: Working Fine. Thanks :)

Answer (score 19):

A `DateTime` can accept input in its constructor with an alternative calendar, but internally it is *always* stored using the Gregorian equivalent.  So you already have what you are looking for.

```
Calendar umAlQura = new UmAlQuraCalendar();
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1434, 11, 23, umAlQura);

// As a string, it will format with whatever the calendar for the culture is.
Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); // 09/29/2013
Debug.WriteLine(dt.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("ar-SA")));     // 23/11/34

// But the individual integer properties are always Gregorian
Debug.WriteLine(dt.Year);  // 2013
Debug.WriteLine(dt.Month); // 9
Debug.WriteLine(dt.Day);   // 29
```

Going the other direction, you have to get the parts using the methods on the calendar object.

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2013, 9, 29);  // Gregorian

Calendar umAlQura = new UmAlQuraCalendar();

Debug.WriteLine(umAlQura.GetYear(dt));       // 1434
Debug.WriteLine(umAlQura.GetMonth(dt));      // 11
Debug.WriteLine(umAlQura.GetDayOfMonth(dt)); // 23
```

Answer (score 2):

As extension method

```
public static DateTime GregorianToUmAlQura(this DateTime gregorianDate)
{
    Calendar umAlQura = new UmAlQuraCalendar();

    return new DateTime(umAlQura.GetYear(gregorianDate), umAlQura.GetMonth(gregorianDate), umAlQura.GetDayOfMonth(gregorianDate), umAlQura);
}
```