# UmAlQuraCalendar return value

Tags: c#, winforms, umalquracalendar

I am writing a class that deal with UmAlQuraCalendar . one of the functions take  Georgian date and convert it to umalqura. i can do that but the System.DateTime class can't hold UmAlQura dates. it only hold Georgian date. so what return type should i use ?

```
public static >>what data type should go here<< ConvertGeorgianToUmalqura(DateTime gDate)
    {
        // code to convert geogrian to Umalqura goes here

    }
```

what i did is that i made my own class to hold the result :

```
public class UmalquraDateTime
{
   //class code goes here
}
```

is making my own class to make umalqura date as return type is correct ?. is there any .NET type that allow me to pass Umalqura date between methods /classes ?

c# in winforms desktop application.

Comment: Considering that the [UmAlQuraCalendar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar.aspx) class has two *ToDateTime* methods, I think that a *DateTime* can hold a *UmAlQuraCalendar* date.

Comment: tried so much ,it always carry Georgian dates

Comment: Georgian?  Or Gregorian?

Answer (score 0):

Use the UmAlQuraCalendar class: 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.umalquracalendar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Here is a solution:
[Convert between calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19075759/convert-between-calendars)