# C# convert Hebrew calendar date to Gregorian calendar date

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to convert Hebrew  dates (Jewish) to Gregorian date;
how can I do it? 
I tried this, but it's not working:

```
string birth = txtBearthDay.Text+" "+ txtBearthMonth.Text+" " + txtBearthYear.Text;
HebrewCalendar hc = new HebrewCalendar();
CultureInfo jewishCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL");

jewishCulture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = hc;
dt = DateTime.Parse(birth,jewishCulture.DateTimeFormat);
```

Comment: Working with Dates is a pain. The kind that can drive people borderline insane: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wpm-gesOY | That being said, for dates after the start of the Unix Epoch (1.1.1970), .NET has *exceptional* support. Usually stuff like Callendar, Culture and Formats are extracted from Windows. But of course you can override it. I actually found this little example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19075881/3346583

Comment: The reason for the limitation is, that internally all taht DateTime saves is the number of Ticks since start of the Unix Epoch. Every other property - including the string representation - are just a interpretation of that value. For dates before the Unix Epoch, it becomes Historian Hard.

Comment: Would you be ok with correcting the spelling of `Bearth` to `Birth` within your code, so it's not so distracting?

Comment: Apparently people hate me giving you relevant background infroamtion, so I have to delete my answer.

Answer (score 4):

It's actually surprisingly simple:

```cs
new DateTime(5780, 5, 7, new HebrewCalendar())
```

This will return a DateTime object with Gregorian property values (2020-02-02), as the properties of a DateTime are rendered with the Gregorian calendar. If you want to get the Hebrew calendar values back out of the DateTime, you must explicitly query the `HebrewCalendar` class.

Answer (score 1):

Try `string date_in_oth_culture = dt.ToString(new CultureInfo("he-IL");`.
I hope it helps.

---

**Edit**: Sorry, I misunderstood what you mean. You can find more informations about how to use `HebrewCalendar` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/api/system.globalization.hebrewcalendar?view=netframework-4.8).

---

**Edit 2**:
Unfortunately neither the code on the documentation seems working and on the internet I couldn't find anything.

A solution might be useing `HebrewCalendar` to calculate new dates and then use a switch statement to translate them yourself.

```
HebrewCalendar hc = new HebrewCalendar();
CultureInfo culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("he-IL");
culture.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = hc;

DateTime hebrDate = hc.ToDateTime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond, era); // Converts Hebrew date into Gregorian date


DateTime gregDate = new DateTime(2020, 2, 1); // Gregorian date

string hebrMonth;
switch(hc.GetMonth(gregDate))
{
  case 1:
    hebrMonth = "___";
    break;
  case 2:
    hebrMonth = "___";
    break;
  // And so on
}

string finalDate = hc.getDayOfMonth(gregDate) + " " + hebrMonth + " " + hc.getYear(gregDate) + " " + hc.getEra(gregDate);
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Try something like: `var dob = DateTime.Parse("[Gregorian DateTime]", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); var hc = new HebrewCalendar(); var hebrewDate = new DateTime(hc.GetYear(dob), hc.GetMonth(dob), hc.GetDayOfMonth(dob));`

Comment: @Jimi I've tried your code, but it doesn't answer the initial question (hebrew -> gregorian) and it doesn't fix problems (as far as I see) in my answer. Tell me if I'm wrong (explaining what or where I'm wrong and possibly a suggestion to solve).

Comment: That's for the Hebrew DateTime, now you just create a new DateTime from it ~in the same way: `var gregorianDate = new DateTime(hebrewDate.Year, hebrewDate.Month, hebrewDate.Day, hc);`  (`hc` is the Hebrew calendar created in the previous comment :). So you have both ways.